# GCC cmath compile type conflict

Tags: c++, g++, cmath

I am trying to compile ns2.34 with my laptop(MAC OS10.8). After several issues solved, now I come across with this problem:

```
In file included from /opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/complex:44:0,
             from /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_complex.hpp:12,
             from /opt/local/include/boost/type_traits.hpp:49,
             from /opt/local/include/boost/pending/property.hpp:13,
             from /opt/local/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:27,
             from ./more_leastCost/leastcost.h:16,
             from ./mobile/god.h:57,
             from gaf/gaf.cc:53:
/opt/local/include/gcc48/c++/cmath:99:16: error: 'template<class _Tp> typename
 __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_integer<_Tp>::__value, double>::__type std::abs(_Tp)'
 conflicts with previous using declaration 'template<class Type> Type abs(Type)'
 abs(_Tp __x)
            ^
make: *** [gaf/gaf.o] Error 1
```

It seems to me that the error is caused by a conflict within GCC? Have any people met with this problem before?

Comment: Can you show the code that causes this error? Ideally, can you narrow it down to a small self-contained example?

Comment: The declaration `abs(Type)` doesn't come from gcc. You could preprocess the file (`-E`) and look for that declaration. Also look for relevant `using` directives.

Comment: Looks like you have a `using namespace blah;` somewhere, and `blah::abs()` exists. Note that Boost has its own `abs`, and I bet that's what is conflicting. Namespaces exist to avoid such conflicts, and this is why `using namespace ...;` statements are so widely discouraged.

Comment: I think that is the reason! I will try to find it out!